# how to use redirect_to in omniauth strategies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, module, omniauth

I got a scenario that under certain condition in build_access_token method in my customized OmniAuth::Strategies module, I need to redirect to browser to another link. But I got NoMethodError for redirect_to (because strategy is in Rack context).

```
redirect_to new_path
```

I also tried

```
Rack::Response.new(["302 Moved"], 302, 'Location' => new_path).finish
```

But failed. Seems there is a deep call stack for Rack.

If I raise the error in strategies, it can't be catched in ApplicationController.

How can I use redirect_to in OmniAuth::Strategies?

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for my scenario. From the `build_access_token`, I create and return an `empty access_token` with a customized flag. So the callback controller can process the flag and do redirect.

It's **hard** to do redirect in `callback_phase (OmniAuth::Strategies)` within Rack context, since there are quite a deep call stack.